# How do you create angular2 component with ngNonBindable attribute?

Tags: angular

I want to create a component that by default has ngNonBindable attribute. This is a simplified version of it:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'non-bindable',
  host: {
    ngNonBindable: 'true'
  }
})
class NonBindableComponent {}

<!-- And use it in your app.component.html -->
<non-bindable>Helo {{name}}!</non-bindable>
```

Expected display:

```
Helo {{name}}!
```

However it still interpolates the {{name}} and display:

```
Hello !
```

I know I can do this on the app.component.html

```
<non-bindable ngNonBindable>Helo {{name}}!</non-bindable>
```

Is there a way to make this so I don't have to add ngNonBindable everytime the component is used?

Comment: Where is component's template? Are you using `<ng-content>`?

Comment: yes using ```<ng-content>```